# How to use the same label in TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfvc, labeling

I am trying to use labels in TFS.  I understand that labels have scope but I don't understand why am I getting an error:

A label with the name 'CB-ARCHIVE-2018' already exists. Do you want to continue? The existing label will be replaced.

I created a ('CB-ARCHIVE-2018') labeled for '**$/SourceCode/WebService**' and I am trying to use the same label for folder '**$/SourceCode/WebService-branch**'.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Typo? Or are the scopes identical?

Comment: Typo.  I fixed it now.  Thanks

Comment: How did you create the label? Unless you explicitly provided both path *and* scope, the default scope would have been $/.

Comment: I added the screenshots to show you what's happening.

Comment: Ahh clear! From the Ui the scope is always set to $/. You need to add the scope. Not sure if you can do it in the ui, the name would become `CB-ARCHIVE-2018@$/SourceCode/Webservice`. If that doesn't work, use the commandline `tf label CB-ARCHIVE-2018@$/SourceCode/Webservice  $/SourceCode/Webservice`

Comment: Looking at the dialog, isn't the scope the path in the dialog?

Comment: Nope that's the items you want to include in the label, not the scope of it.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Visual Studio to apply a label that already exists, the operation removes the label from all file versions and then applies the label. From the command prompt, however, the label operation is additive. See [Label Command (Team Foundation Version Control)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/label-command-team-foundation-version-control?view=vsts). So use tf command to add the exist label:

```
tf label CB-ARCHIVE-2018 $/SourceCode/WebService-branch /collection:http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

Check the link below for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/use-labels-take-snapshot-your-files?view=vsts#apply-a-label

Comment: As I mentioned when you use` Visual Studio` to apply a label that already exists, you'll get this warning, you need to use `tf label` command instead.

Answer (score 1):

Labels are a bit if a confusing beast in TFVC, mostly because the Ui doesn't enable all options.

From the Ui the scope is always set to $/. The path you specify tells Visual Studio which files/folders to include in the label.

You could try adding `@$/SourceCode/Webservice` to the label name, not sure if that works.

The sure way to specify a label scope is from the commandline from where you can issue the following command to apply the label:

```
tf.exe vc label CB-ARCHIVE-2018@$/SourceCode/Webservice  $/SourceCode/Webservice
```

Label scopes can't intercect, so you'll probably need to delete the existing labels first.